# Swift: Setting up a Game Scene in a Single View Application

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm currently attempting to develop games using the sprite kit on a single view application because there is more to my app than a game. I've found this method quite unorthodox because most games are made by directly selecting the game template at the beginning of the project. I have managed to add the sprite kit framework and I've got the fps, draws, node to show. However I've found on native sprite kit projects they have **GameScene.sks**, and a pre setup **GameScene.swift** file into their project. How would I set them up? Do I copy the code and put it into a GameScene.swift file and link it to my GameViewController? How would I find and setup the GameScene.sks file?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why somebody down voted this question, maybe because the question is not descriptive, but anyway,  to create a new scene, on the menu, select File -> New -> File,  go to iOS -> Resource, and select SpriteKit Scene,  this is will create a new Scene template for you